# Parsing JSON block by block

Tags: json, perl, parsing, data-structures, perl-data-structures

I have a JSON  file with a list of customers and date.

The file looks like this:

```
{
"Customers": [
{
  "Customer": "Customer Name Here",
  "Company": "Super Coffee",
  "First Name": "First Name Here",
  "Main Phone": "777-777-7777",
  "Fax": "777-777-7777",
  "Bill to 1": "Billing Address One",
  "Bill to 2": "Billing Address Two",
  "Bill to 3": "Billing Address Three",
  "Ship to 1": "Shipping Address One",
  "Ship to 2": "Shipping Address Two",
  "Ship to 3": "Shipping Address Three",
  "Customer Type": "Dealer/Retail"
},
{
  "Customer": "Customer Name Here",
  "Company": "Turtle Mountain Welding",
  "First Name": "First Name Here",
  "Main Phone": "777-777-7777",
  "Fax": "777-777-7777",
  "Bill to 1": "Billing Address One",
  "Bill to 2": "Billing Address Two",
  "Bill to 3": "Billing Address Three",
  "Ship to 1": "Shipping Address One",
  "Ship to 2": "Shipping Address Two",
  "Ship to 3": "Shipping Address Three",
  "Customer Type": "Dealer/Retail"
},
{
  "Customer": "Customer Name Here",
  "Company": "Mountain Equipment Coop",
  "First Name": "First Name Here",
  "Main Phone": "777-777-7777",
  "Fax": "777-777-7777",
  "Bill to 1": "Billing Address One",
  "Bill to 2": "Billing Address Two",
  "Bill to 3": "Billing Address Three",
  "Ship to 1": "Shipping Address One",
  "Ship to 2": "Shipping Address Two",
  "Ship to 3": "Shipping Address Three",
  "Customer Type": "Dealer/Retail"
},
{
  "Customer": "Customer Name Here",
  "Company": "Best Soup Inc.",
  "First Name": "First Name Here",
  "Main Phone": "777-777-7777",
  "Fax": "777-777-7777",
  "Bill to 1": "Billing Address One",
  "Bill to 2": "Billing Address Two",
  "Bill to 3": "Billing Address Three",
  "Ship to 1": "Shipping Address One",
  "Ship to 2": "Shipping Address Two",
  "Ship to 3": "Shipping Address Three",
  "Customer Type": "Dealer/Retail"
}
]
}
```

I need to be able to extract data from the file block by block, instead of line by line.

I'm used to parsing files line by line to get the data, but with JSON, I need to somehow read it block by block (or more precisely, object by object?). I need to read it by whats inside the brackets for each customer. That way I can write a script that extracts the data I need, and builds a CSV file from it.

For example:

```
i="1"
for file in *.json; do
     customername=$(jsonblock$i:customername);
     customerAddress=$(jsonblock$i:customeraddress);
     etc...
     i=$[i+1]
done
```

I understand how this is done when reading a file line by line, but how can I read each JSON block as if it was a line so to speak?

Comment: are you asking for any language as long as it parses json?

Comment: i suggest use token... is your json file by chance a link?

Comment: This would be easy to do in a shell script with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), except that `jq` doesn't appear to handle key names with whitespace.  I would reach for Python instead of a shell script for handling JSON documents.

Comment: MAC: I'm not sure what you mean by "is your json file a link".  Any language will do.  The right tool for the job is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is simply to print the JSON data in CSV format then you are asking the wrong question. You should parse the entire JSON document and process the `Customers` array item by item.

Using Perl's [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) and [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) modules, that would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON 'from_json';
use Text::CSV ();

my @columns = (
  'Bill to 1',  'Bill to 2',     'Bill to 3', 'Company',
  'Customer',   'Customer Type', 'Fax',       'First Name',
  'Main Phone', 'Ship to 1',     'Ship to 2', 'Ship to 3',
);

my $out_fh = \*STDOUT;
my $json_file = 'customers.json';

my $data = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $json_file or die qq{Unable to open "$json_file" for input: $!};
  local $/;
  from_json(<$fh>);
};
my $customers = $data->{Customers};

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ eol => $/ });
$csv->print($out_fh, \@columns);

for my $customer ( @$customers ) {
  $csv->print($out_fh, [ @{$customer}{@columns} ]);
}
```

**output**

```
"Bill to 1","Bill to 2","Bill to 3",Company,Customer,"Customer Type",Fax,"First Name","Main Phone","Ship to 1","Ship to 2","Ship to 3"
"Billing Address One","Billing Address Two","Billing Address Three","Super Coffee","Customer Name Here",Dealer/Retail,777-777-7777,"First Name Here",777-777-7777,"Shipping Address One","Shipping Address Two","Shipping Address Three"
"Billing Address One","Billing Address Two","Billing Address Three","Turtle Mountain Welding","Customer Name Here",Dealer/Retail,777-777-7777,"First Name Here",777-777-7777,"Shipping Address One","Shipping Address Two","Shipping Address Three"
"Billing Address One","Billing Address Two","Billing Address Three","Mountain Equipment Coop","Customer Name Here",Dealer/Retail,777-777-7777,"First Name Here",777-777-7777,"Shipping Address One","Shipping Address Two","Shipping Address Three"
"Billing Address One","Billing Address Two","Billing Address Three","Best Soup Inc.","Customer Name Here",Dealer/Retail,777-777-7777,"First Name Here",777-777-7777,"Shipping Address One","Shipping Address Two","Shipping Address Three"
```

Comment: I do need to convert it to CSV, but I don't need every item in each block.  I only need some of the items, but the same items from all blocks.

Comment: @DavidProvost: Okay, but I don't see how I can include that in my answer as I don't know how you want to specify *which* items you need. It may be as simple as modifying the `@columns` array

Comment: Modifying the `@columns` array indeed filters the output to specific data.

Comment: How do I change `$out_fh` from STDOUT to a text file?

Comment: You can either change the assignment statement to `open my $out_fh, '>', 'customers.csv' or die $!;` or you can redirect the output on the command line with `json_to_csv.pl > customers.csv`

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the JSON above (which was modified since the provided data was invalid) the following script will parse and print the `"Company:"` part of each block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use JSON;   
use IO::All;     
use v5.16;

my $data < io 'Our_Customers.json';
my $customers_list = decode_json($data)->{"Customers"};                

for my $customer (@$customers_list) {
   say $customer->{"Company"} ;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Super Coffee
Turtle Mountain Welding
Mountain Equipment Coop
Best Soup Inc.
```

The script uses [`IO::All`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) and [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) to read and parse (`decode_json`) the file.

In this example the JSON data is simply mapped to a Perl data-structure (an [Array of Hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES)) which corresponds neatly with  the JSON data. We can then access each array element (*i.e* each *hash* in the *array*) and then access the data inside the hashes by key names. Perl has very flexible data-munging and access functions which makes working with JSON data pretty pleasant.

The keys for each data block come from the equivalent part of the JSON file.  If we shift an element off the array it will be a hash and we access can see the `keys` and `values` of the element like this:

```
say for keys shift $customers_list ;

Customer Type
First Name
Bill to 2
Main Phone
...
```

The values for each key are accessed using the `$element->{"key"}` syntax you see in the `for` loop.

---

It's best to validate JSON data before posting it to SO - [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and similar services can help with that.

Comment: I installed the perl module dependencies to run your code. I am getting the following error: Not an ARRAY reference at ./parse-json.pl line 10.

Comment: The reason it wasn't parsing is because even though JSON was valid, the hash array has to begin with square brackets.  I removed the opening curly brace brackets and title and the script works.  Thanks for answer, this is my first real world application of perl and I can't wait to learn more!

Comment: perhaps  `for my $customer (@{$customers_list->{Customers}}) ...`  ?

Comment: ... Or `my $c2 = decode_json($data)->{Customers};
for my $c (@$c2) { ... }`

Comment: @DavidProvost - the error you see is because I was running the script with the modified JSON file. I had edited your post to force the JSON to be "valid". By adding the parens `{}` back you changed the resultant perl data-structure. You just need to change your code to suit/ as @JJoao suggests. I will edit my response to match the current JSON in your post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl and the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#INCREMENTAL_PARSING) library you could incrementally parse each item in a JSON list but you'll need to munge the json so that it's not actually json but rather a list of json objects not separated by a comma.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use JSON;
my $json = JSON->new;
while (<>) {
    my $obj_or_undef = eval { $json->incr_parse( $_ ); };
    # Wait until its found a whole object
    if (ref $obj_or_undef) {
        say join ",", map {$obj_or_undef->{$_}} sort keys %$obj_or_undef;
    }
}
```

For customers.json (which is no longer quite json):

```
{ 
    "some key" : "some value"
} {
    "other key" : "other value"
}
```

To run:

```
$ perl demo.pl < customers.json
some value
other value
$ perl demo.pl < customers.json > customer.csv
```